# Count Duplicates with Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have to make a summary from a Google Sheets database that should count all duplicates, it should be under the same date and the same account. Here's a sample below.

```
Date            Account    # Checked Escalations
11/7/2023   123ABC           3
11/7/2023   456ASD           1
11/8/2023   789JKL           3
```

I tried what I could find, even tried MAP and COUNTIFS.

The criteria should be the same date and same account.

Comment: What would be your desired output from given data?